# Make vim listen to any key stroke

Tags: vim

I would like to set some shortcut for `set relativenumber` and than I would like to `set number` as far I will put any key that is not number or `hjkl` and pass it key to active buffer. It would be really usefull for me. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you add a step by step description of the behavior you want?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Vim help give several examples on how you can accomplish this task. You should read [`:help 05.3`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#05.3),  [`:help 40.1`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.1) and [vim faq-mapping-keys](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.1).

In order to use <kbd>F4</kbd> to toggle the `'relativenumber'` you can use the following:

```
noremap <silent> <F4> :set relativenumber!<cr>
```